# Allowing access to index.php/customer/account/login with nginx

Tags: magento-1.9, url, nginx, access

I am new to Magento and have setup a new instance manually. I can see the home page successfully but am unable to access
http://xyz/dev/index.php/customer/account/login/
and get a 404 error from nginx.

I have given access to all of dev folder by using this line in etc/nginx/sites-available/default:

```
location /dev/ {
        #       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        autoindex on;
        }
```

The commented line is what I have tried from another online document that did not work. How can I resolve this? I am doing this in incognito mode, if it helps.

P.S: How do I understand this URL structure? Looks new to me.

Comment: have you tried without `index.php` in url?

Comment: No. index.php is in the standard urls. So taking it out will break Magento I think.